# Doesn't work on Android Studio- locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

Tags: android, android-studio, android-location, android-gps

I'm trying to find make the following line work:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

The studio marks it as Error and suggests to check that all permissions are set or handling a SecurityException.

I think that I have set all the necessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

But still , it does not work.

Did someone have the same problem ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Whats your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: If only the studio marked it as red, it's fined. Try to compile. I was like that too, but compile is fined although it marked that as red

Comment: check for dynamic permissions .

Answer (score 0):

you can use these code.In android studio you have to check dynamic permission at run time

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {

            getLocation();

        }
```

and

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                getLocation();


            }
            break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in Marshmallow, permissions are asked at runtime to the user.So we need to handle wheather user has granted that particular permission or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```